# End-of-line characters flip flop in Eclipse settings

Tags: eclipse, git, settings, eol

Eclipse stores some project settings in the file `.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml` changing end-of-line characters and this is creating unnecessary commits and polluting the repository. Here's the file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faceted-project>                                 (this EOL flip-flops)
  <installed facet="jst.utility" version="1.0"/>  (this EOL flip-flops)
  <installed facet="java" version="11"/>
</faceted-project>
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Developer #1 opens the project in **Windows**, and Eclipse changes the end-of-line chars to `\r\n`; then this developer commits to the repository.
2. Then, developer #2 opens the project in **Linux**, and Eclipse changes the end-of-line chars to `\n`; then this developer commits to the repository.
3. Developer #1 pulls the changes in **Windows**, and EOL flip-flops again. Rinse and repeat.

This is happening with four settings files (so far), so they are committed to the git repository pretty much on every single commit; and this is polluting the repository.

Is there a way of telling Eclipse to use either `\r\n` or `\n` for good? Workspace and project settings don't seem to affect "settings files", but only "source code" files.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible approaches here.  One is not to store editor configuration in the repository, which is generally the recommended approach.  Different people use different editors on different systems, and anything other than a generic editor configuration can contain settings that aren't applicable to all systems.

The other way, if you want to store them anyway, is to use a `.gitattributes` file in your repository, and then add a line like the following:

```
.settings/*.xml text
```

Then run `git add --renormalize .`.  That will force the line endings in the repository to LF and tell Git, by default, to check out the native line endings.  Of course, the user can configure Git to do something different if it's appropriate to their system.

Then when the user modifies the file, the endings will be appropriate for their platform and it won't cause Git to show things that are modified.  If the user does attempt to commit it, the file will be normalized, and no change will occur.

You can also add `* text=auto` to the `.gitattributes` file, which will let Git determine which files should have their line endings normalized based on whether they're detected as binary or text.  You can see more about how to adjust these settings in the `gitattributes(5)` man page.

Comment: "Then when the user modifies the file..." -- the user does not modify it. Eclipse silently does it behind the scenes, and the developer only finds out when it's commit time. But I hear you; maybe these files should be treated as "assume-unchanged".

Comment: Then read it as, "Then when Eclipse modifies the file….".  Also, that's not a supported use  for assume-unchanged and doing that will likely break in surprising ways.